# Can we change browser's native video player's css ? if not what is the lightest html5 video player plugin which can be stylise easy?

Tags: jquery, css, html, video, controls

Is it possible to just use audio control and hide others from html5 video controls bar?

I want to hide control bar and just use audio turn off/on button. I read [revelant article on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp) but can't find the solution.

Is it possible to change css positions audio mute button? i marked on this picture.

[Here is jsFiddle sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/YZT5s/5/)

[image]

Edit: Do we have any chance to change video control's css and re-style them for our needs?

**If not, what is best and light html5 video player we can stylise ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can style the native controls to some extend by addressing the Shadow DOM, using browser vendor specific pseudo element selectors like `video::-webkit-media-controls-panel`, but—like @heff said—these controls differ between browsers, and building your own offers more control. Remember: html[5] Video is more than just the `video` tag; it comes with a nice (JavaScript) API.

Comment: Could you expand your answer about changing native control's pseudo selector's and be more specific with examples please?

Comment: Not change the pseudo selector, but using CSS pseudo element selectors (see [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements)) to target the visual appearance of [Shadow DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) elements. [Discover the Dark side with Shadow DOM](http://blog.romanliutikov.com/coding/discover-the-dark-side-with-shadow-dom/) would probably be a good read for your case.

Comment: At least we have still hope on -webkit- browsers, and this is the first time i am hearing about Shadow DOM. Thanks for the answer, +100 is yours.

Comment: Other Web browsers also maintain a shadow DOM, but their labels and levels of accessibility differ a lot. Good luck with your project(s), and thanks for the bounty!

Comment: Shadow dom link is dead, here is online one: http://blog.romanliutikov.com/blog/discover-the-dark-side-with-shadow-dom/

Comment: I noticed the link to my old article is still relevant but the article itself is gone already. So I've updated and upgraded it, it's here right now http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/62104274790/web-components I'll fix the old link when figure out how it can be done on Tumblr.

Answer (score 6):

Not if you're using the browser's native controls. There's no access to modify the native controls, and even if there were, the controls are different between browsers.

You could [build your own volume control](http://blog.steveheffernan.com/2010/04/how-to-build-an-html5-video-player/) that overlays the video and turn the native controls off.

Or you could use an [HTML5 video player](http://videojs.com) (a javascript library for video) and modify the CSS for it.

Comment: check out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/#toc-fun-js for some ideas.

Answer (score 5):

The html5 video tag has some css options for its control bar.

For instance, if you want to hide the mute button you can use:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Here are all the css options I'm aware of:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-picture-in-picture-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button {}
video::-webkit-media-controls-toggle-closed-captions-button {}
video::-webkit-full-page-media::-webkit-media-controls-panel {}
```